# Python: Remove member from instance

Tags: python, reflection

Im adding callable objects to a instance of a class A at runtime using the `__dict__` property. At some point though I want to remove all added objects from my instance. I thought about storing the initial `__dict__` property in a member `_orgDict` and then execute `self.__dict__ = self._orgDict` later. Im wondering whether:

- This works at all?
- The removed objects are really deleted or just not contained in my instance anymore?

Comment: It might be better if you explained why exactly you think you need this. There are probably much better ways to solve your problem, such as storing your callable objects in a separate dictionary that stores nothing else.

Comment: @Duncan Im injecting asm code into a foreign process and want to make certain asm functions callable through an adapter (namely the callable objects). Currently im writing the class which takes the compiled code and injects it into the process. I thought about adding the adapters to instances of these class, but I like the idea with an extra dictionary. It make things more easier and clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test shows that reassigning an instance `__dict__` seems to work:

```
>>> class B(object): 
       pass
>>> b = B()
>>> b.b = 6
>>> b.b
6
>>> b.__dict__ = {}
>>> b.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#57>", line 1, in <module>
    b.b
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'b'
```

However, I'm not sure whether this is guaranteed, or if it just happens to work. Especially in terms of supporting non-C Pythons, you may want to be careful.

Answer (score 7):

You mean the [del](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) statement?

```
del(instance.attribute)
```

Comment: No this is not what the question is about. Im asking whether the assigment is enough to get the objects deleted or I ned to delete them manually

Comment: @Paranaix: This would be safer than your dictionary assignment which would also remove anything else that might have changed since you saved the original (potentially not just the other objects you added).

Comment: @martineau This approach relies on the fact that i know which member/members I want to delete at the time i wrote the code (lets call it compile time). But thats actually not the case. Im writing a class which can hold abitrary additional objects at runtime. Although im really favoring Duncans suggestion.

Comment: @Paranaix: Yes, storing all the objects in a container would be safer in terms of unintended side-effects, as well as easier to modify and extend later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to override(delete) the objects by assignment. Here is the example.

```
>>> class callable_objects:
    def __init__(self, name, fame=None):
        self.name = name
            self.fame = fame
        def _name(self):
            if self.name[0] in ["a","b","c","d","e"]:
                self._fame("1")
            else:
                self._fame("2")
        def _fame(self, ifame):
            if ifame == "1":
                print "Ur fame is bad"
            else:
                print "Ur fame is very bad"

>>> c = callable_objects("ameet")
>>> callable_objects.__dict__ 
{'__module__': '__main__', '_fame': <function _fame at 0x02B5C370>, '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x02B5C330>, '_name': <function _name at 0x02B5C2F0>}
>>> c.__dict__
{'name': 'ameet', 'fame': None}
>>> callable_objects.__dict__ = c.__dict__
>>> callable_objects.__dict__
{'name': 'ameet', 'fame': None}
```